# Worth microcontroller learning suggestion

Tags: microcontroller

Probably this kind of question should be asked on quora, but I am still asking here because I found this website incredibly reliable and the answers are from real gems in this field.
Now coming to the question, I am aiming at designing microcontroller based products, to be specific 1.microcontroller based power banks, 2.fast chargers. 3.domestic inverters. 4.smart lights wifi based.

I am currently studying 8051 for understanding microcontrollers in a nutshell, I know learning 8051 will not probably help me directly to understand the microcontroller used in the products I mentioned above. So I want some advise on which microcontroller should I learn once I finish learning 8051 so that it would be relevant in designing those product I have mentioned?

Comment: Why not just start designing one of those devices, pick an appropriate micro and learn in the process of doing the job?  Why  put off getting your hands dirty?

Comment: Can you please suggest me will PIC a good choice to learn?

Comment: Why would a power bank need a microcontroller? Or fast charger? Anything with WiFi means it's most likely a SoC, not a MCU. @Sayan which PIC you mean? There's so many different models, from very small and slow to very large and powerful devices. There is no one PIC as they are all different.

Comment: If you intend on using the particular PIC in your application it might be appropriate, but lower end PICs are not much different from an 8051. Doing a WiFi application would be a different experience.

Comment: @Justme As far as I know there is a chip which negotiate with the device  when to increase voltage in fast charger, isn't that microcontroller?

Comment: @Sayan Such chip may or may not be microcontrollers. Even if they would be microcontrollers, who says you can program them yourself, or why would there even be need for it, if it comes with a factory programmed firmware. It's a chip that negotiates voltage, and buyer/user does not need to know how it is does the job, as long as it does the job.

Answer (score 1):

Since this question is opinion based, and this site has no. of veterans in this field, I really don't expect my answer to be the best one but let me share my experience with you. I am a beginner in microcontroller world.

First things first, I started off with Arduino to visualize how the code actually works in real life electronics. I also learnt to use no. of sensors like Ultrasonic, RTC, and so on.

Luckily I had a subject called "Microprocessor" in my Bachelor's classes which turned out to be incredibly helpful for me in understanding of how these little things shape the world. I had had learnt the concept of registers, flags, interrupts, and many things that made the journey of my learning absolutely helpful.
I don't have experience with 8051 but I learnt 8085 microprocessor in my university.

Then, I dared to jump into Atmega328P which is the microcontroller used in Arduino Uno. I grabbed the book "Make:AVR" by Eliott Williams and started tinkering with AVR. In the process, I learnt how Arduino functions in the register level. Since I had concept of Arduino, I didn't have much trouble with AVR. I got to learn communication buses, ADCs, and what not.

Now, I am confident that I can program Atmega328P to do what I need to. You don't only learn how to program those microcontroller. You learn many small things that make the real difference. Hope my answer is somehow helpful for you.

Comment: Thanks, this is really a good advice for me.

Comment: "Make" series are really interesting to hobbysts.